# Is Spark sql query on view running on the DF?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I've created a view in hive, and it's a complex query (has joins, unions, etc.).
When I'm executing the query on a DF, does the Catalyst & Tungsten work or is it 100% hive?
What I'm trying to ask is - can I get the query the view is executing and then use the spark sql to execute the query - with Catalyst & Tungsten improvements?

Example:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from view")
```

the view query is running on hive (hive context) and therefor not so efficient.

vs

```
val str = getQuery...
sqlContext.sql("*actual query*")..
```

It's not a dataset so I'm not sure it'll be more efficient, but I'm trynig to figure out how to do so..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> When I'm executing the query on a DF, does the Catalyst & Tungsten
>   work or is it 100% hive?

- Tungsten became the default in Spark 1.5 and can be enabled in earlier versions by setting `spark.sql.tungsten.enabled` = true (or disabled in later versions by setting this to false). Even without Tungsten, Spark SQL uses a columnar storage format with Kryo serialization to minimize storage cost.
- Hive query  and Spark Dataframe both uses catalist optimizer.

see you enabled tungsten or not by this property `spark.sql.tungsten.enabled`

> What I'm trying to ask is - can I get the query the view is executing
>   and then use the spark sql to execute the query - with Catalyst &
>   Tungsten improvements?

- **From code** : see the execution by `df.explain` to see the internals of it.
- **From Spark UI** :

Spark 1.5 adds visualization of SQL and DataFrame query plans in the web UI, with dynamic update of operational metrics such as the selectivity of a filter operator and the runtime memory usage of aggregations and joins. Below is an example of a plan visualization from the web UI. ([source](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/09/announcing-apache-spark-1-5.html))
[image]